# Angular2 ClockPicker

Tags: angular, timepicker, clockpicker

I am currently exploring all alternatives of **clockpicker** for a web app working with **Angular 2**

Something like 
http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/ for exemple.

I have made researches but everything seems not easy to set up.

Has anyone came across any good solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you found an answer yet? i am looking for something similar. thx

Comment: @jay infortunatly no ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1st step**

Use angular client (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create a new project:

`ng new clockpicker-example`

**2nd step**

Install necessary packages:

`npm install jquery --save-dev`

`npm install jquery --save-dev`

`npm install clockpicker --save-dev`

`npm install @types/clockpicker --save-dev`

**3rd step**

Inside .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/clockpicker/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/clockpicker/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js"
  ],
```

**4th step**

create a file called `clockpicker.directive.ts`

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
@Directive({
   selector: '[appClockPicker]'
})


export class ClockPickerDirective implements OnInit {
   constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     $(this.el.nativeElement).clockpicker({
       placement: 'bottom',
       align: 'left',
       donetext: 'Done',
       afterDone: () => {
         console.log('done');
       }
     });
   }
}
```

**5th step**

Inside `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="input-group" appClockPicker>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**6th step**

Inside `typings.d.ts` add:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;
```

Comment: Cool, let me know if it worked. U also need to add ClockiPickerDirective to declarationsin app.module.ts. I forgot to add that. If it doesn't work I can create a github repo with a working exampel

Comment: Hi @D1scobo1 Thanks for a great answer, but unfortunately, I can't get it working. The bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js script doesn't seem to run. If you would create a repo with a working example, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Here is the repo: https://github.com/LorenzHW/ClockPicker
I created that with Ang CLI 6. 
Furthermore I declared the typings for jQuery inside the directive. You probably shouldn't do that for a real application. Not sure where to define those typings with Angular 6.
Check that your paths are correct to the node_modules inside angular.json!

Comment: what not use `--save` to install jquery and clockpicker?